# Assign multiple if-elif conditions into one variable

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement, plotly

I am creating a `font_color` variable that I will insert into the following:

```
fig_positions = go.Figure(data=go.Table(
            header=dict(values=list(df_new.columns)),
            cells=dict(values=[df_new['Block Number'],
                               df_new['WoW Chg%']],
                       font=dict(color=create_font_color(df_new['WoW Chg%']))
```

Note that the important line is the last line with the `create_font_color(df_new['WoW Chg%'])` function, explained below:

The `font_color`, however, changes depending on the value.

Since I need to feed the `color` parameter of `plotly.go.Table()`, I want to assign the following logic to the `font_color` variable (I tried creating this function, but realized it does not work because it does not include every logic into one variable):

```
    def create_font_color(series: pd.Series):
        for boolv in series:
            if boolv <= -0.05:
                font_color = ['black'] * 14 + ['black' if boolv else 'red' for boolv in series]

            elif -0.05 < boolv <= 0:
                font_color = ['black'] * 14 + ['black' for boolv in series]

            elif 0 <= boolv < 0.05:
                font_color = ['black'] * 14 + ['black' for boolv in series]

            else:
                font_color = ['black'] * 14 + ['black' if boolv else 'green' for boolv in series]

            return font_color
```

How can I create a font_color that includes the logic above (which are 2, basically)?

1. Red if lower than -0.05
2. Black if between -0.05 and 0.05
3. Green if greater than 0.05

Comment: So the *font_color* variable is going to be a string that tells you the color font needs to be?

Comment: Yes, it is an object that has all the logic of what the color of each row needs to be. The hardest challenge is including all the logic into one variable because I can't feed something else to the `font=` parameter.

Comment: the `return` statement ends the loop, so you only process the first element of `series`. I suspect what you want is `series.apply(...)`

Comment: Thanks. Still, the logic should be included into one variable, because that's what I need to feed into the `font=` parameter. It's probably going to look like a mess.

Comment: I do not want to modify the series. I want to modify the color of the font based on the value in the series.